# How to create a makefile for c++ when .o file will be provided later

Tags: c++, makefile

My project contains a *sub.h* file that I was instructed to only have the following contents:

```
int sub(int n, int *A, int *B, int *C);
```

*sub.h* performs an unspecified action on 3 arrays taken from an *input.txt* file.

The instructions say that the *sub.o* will be provided later when the project is submitted. My question is, how do I create a makefile for a given *.o* file that I cannot access yet? It is difficult for me to tell whether or not my makefile will be successful since I do not have the *sub.o*.

The project only contains *main.cpp*, *sub.h*, and the makefile.

Here's what I have for the makefile so far:

```
project: main.o sub.o
    g++ main.o message.o -o project

main.o: main.cpp sub.h
    g++ -c -g main.cpp

clean:
    rm main.o sub.o project
```

Comment: Where does `message.o` come from? You also haven't any source for that. Why is `sub.o` removed by `clean`, although you can't build it again once you've deleted it?

Comment: Remove any occurrences of `sub.o` from the *makefile* until the necessary *sub.cpp* file is provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a `sub.cpp` that provides some implementation of `sub()` and make your Makefile build the `sub.o`.

When you submit the project, put the provided `sub.o` where it is supposed to be generated. In such case, the "real" `sub.o` will be used to compile your binary.

Comment: I would do that, but I am not allowed to include any new files such as sub.cpp

Comment: @techin424 You could instruct the Makefile to generate one. Is it allowed?

Comment: remove sub.cpp right before submitting your code then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile to an executable (i.e. link) if you have a missing object file. But you can (only) compile main.c to an object file - at this stage it doesn't matter that sub is undefined. I can only assume that the linking happens when you submit.

This main.c will compile to an object:

```
int sub(int n, int *A, int *B, int *C);

int main()
{
  int n = 0; 
  int* A = 0;
  int* B = 0;
  int* C = 0;

  sub(n, A, B, C);
}
```

using e.g.

```
gcc -c main.cpp
```

and if you do get hold of sub.o you can link using

```
gcc main.o sub.o -o project
```